# Trouble With Loop

Tags: vb.net, loops

I have a loop that will save videos from my resources (My.Resources.*file*) to a path (in this case, it's C:\Users*username*\AppData\Local\Temp*video number*.avi). This loop will go on for 10 videos that I have in resources, it will save all of them to that same path.
Here's my code:

```
Sub SaveAllVideos()
        Dim x As Integer
        Dim y As Object
        Dim z As Object
        Do Until x = 11
            x += 1
            y = "My.Resources." & "_" & x
            z = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) & "\Temp\" & x & ".avi"
            Dim b As Byte() = y
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(z, y, False)
        Loop
    End Sub
```

The problem is at

```
Dim b As Byte() = y
```

I'll get "InvalidCastException. Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'.". Doing this:

```
Dim b As Byte() = My.Resources.*resource*
```

Works fine, so I'm not sure why mine doesn't work, because y is "My.Resources._*number*". So, can anyone help me out here? And maybe explain why what I did doesn't work?

EDIT: Tried to convert the string to byte somehow (as stated in comments), right now I'm here:

```
y = "My.Resources." & "_" & x 
Dim w As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(y) 
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(z, w, False)
```

This runs and saves the video, but it only contains the text "My.Resources._1" in it. Some help anyone?

EDIT2: Solved this by myself, here's my final code

```
Sub SaveAllVideos()
        Dim x As Integer
        Dim y As Object
        Dim z As Object
        Do Until x = 10
            x += 1
            y = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("_" & x)
            z = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) & "\Temp\" & x & ".avi"
            Dim b As Byte() = y
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(z, b, False)
        Loop
    End Sub
```

Comment: `My.Resources.Whatever` <> "My.Resources.Whatever" as a string.

Comment: Is there a way to maybe convert the string somehow?

Comment: The compiler builds a `Byte()` and that is the type that `My.Resources.Whatever` is where "My.Resources.Whatever" is a string and not a `Byte()`

Comment: Alright, I tried converting it by doing ` y = "My.Resources." & "_" & x
            Dim w As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(y)
            Dim b As Byte() = w` however I got the error that it's actually a 1 "dimensional array of byte"

Comment: Ok, so solved my comment before by adding brackets after the byte in the "dim w as byte" so now I have this: ` y = "My.Resources." & "_" & x
            Dim w As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(y)
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(z, w, False)` this runs, but it doesn't actually save the file correctly.

Comment: What do you need? `"My.Resources.*"` as a byte array or the actual content from that key in the resources files?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim b As Byte() = y
```

Should be

```
Dim b As Byte() = My.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(y)
```